# Merging two Data Frames using Fuzzy/Approximate String Matching in R

Tags: r, fuzzy-search

**DESCRIPTION**

I have two datasets with information that I need to merge. The only common fields that I have are strings that do not perfectly match and a numerical field that can be substantially different

The only way to explain the problem is to show you the data. Here is [a.csv](http://bertelsen.ca/R/a.csv) and [b.csv](http://bertelsen.ca/R/b.csv). I am trying to merge B to A.

There are three fields in B and four in A. Company Name (File A Only), Fund Name, Asset Class, and Assets. So far, my focus has been on attempting to match the Fund Names by replacing words or parts of the strings to create exact matches and then using:

```
a <- read.table(file = "http://bertelsen.ca/R/a.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings=F, strip.white=T, blank.lines.skip=F, stringsAsFactors=T) 
b <- read.table(file = "http://bertelsen.ca/R/b.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings=F, strip.white=T, blank.lines.skip=F, stringsAsFactors=T)
merge(a,b, by="Fund.Name")
```

However, this only brings me to about 30% matching. The rest I have to do by hand.

Assets is a numerical field that is not always correct in either and can vary wildly if the fund has low assets. Asset Class is a string field that is "generally" the same in both files, however, there are discrepancies.

Adding to the complication are the different series of funds, in File B. For example:

> AGF Canadian Value
>
> AGF Canadian Value-D

In these cases, I have to choose the one that is not seried, or choose the one that is called "A", "-A", or "Advisor" as the match.

**QUESTION**

What would you say is the best approach? This excercise is something that I have to do on a monthly basis and matching them manually is incredibly time consuming. Examples of code would be instrumental.

**IDEAS**

One method that I think may work is normalizing the strings based on the first capitalized letter of each word in the string. But I haven't been able to figure out how to pull that off using R.

Another method I considered was creating an index of matches based on a combination of assets, fund name, asset class and company. But again, I'm not sure how to do this with R. Or, for that matter, if it's even possible.

Examples of code, comments, thoughts and direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If we talk about string matching then `?agrep` (in base package).

Comment: Would be great if you can make the data part of the post so we can use the example a few years after posting. Thanks.

Comment: indeed a few more years later on and the data are not there

Comment: It's 6 years ago. I'll look for the data and if I find it, update the question. Although, I think the answers speak to the solutions regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approximate string matching is not a good idea since an incorrect match would invalidate the whole analysis. If the names from each source is the same each time, then building indexes seems the best option to me too. This is easily done in R:

Suppose you have the data:

```
a<-data.frame(name=c('Ace','Bayes'),price=c(10,13))
b<-data.frame(name=c('Ace Co.','Bayes Inc.'),qty=c(9,99))
```

Build an index of names for each source one time, perhaps using pmatch etc. as a starting point and then validating manually.

```
a.idx<-data.frame(name=c('Ace','Bayes'),idx=c(1,2))
b.idx<-data.frame(name=c('Ace Co.','Bayes Inc.'), idx=c(1,2))
```

Then for each run merge using:

```
a.rich<-merge(a,a.idx,by="name")
b.rich<-merge(b,b.idx,by="name")
merge(a.rich,b.rich,by="idx")
```

Which would give us:

```
  idx name.x price     name.y qty
1   1    Ace    10    Ace Co.   9
2   2  Bayes    13 Bayes Inc.  99
```

Comment: The problem is more when the names are dirtier then that. Say when the first word may or may not be short-formed and when the rest of the words may or may not be shortformed either. This shortforming is not consistent inside a single name or accross names.

Answer (score 14):

It's highly recommended to use the [dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) package.

`stringdist_inner_join(a,b, by="Fund.Name")`

Answer (score 9):

One quick suggestion: try to do some matching on the different fields separately before using merge.  The simplest approach is with the `pmatch` function, although R has no shortage of text matching functions (e.g. `agrep`).  Here's a simple example:

```
pmatch(c("med", "mod"), c("mean", "median", "mode"))
```

For your dataset, this matches all the fund names out of `a`:

```
> nrow(merge(a,b,x.by="Fund.Name", y.by="Fund.name"))
[1] 58
> length(which(!is.na(pmatch(a$Fund.Name, b$Fund.name))))
[1] 238
```

Once you create matches, you can easily merge them together using those instead.

Comment: Thanks Shane, your suggestions are always helpful - I'll take a look at these two and let you know how it worked out.

Comment: Yes definitely, great tips Shane.

Comment: The problem is more when the names are dirtier then that. Say when the first word may or may not be short-formed and when the rest of the words may or may not be shortformed either. This shortforming is not consistent inside a single name or accross names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Canada local as well, recognize the fund names.

This is a difficult one as each of the data providers picks their own form for the individual fund names. Some use different structure like all end in either Fund or Class others are all over the place. Each seems to choose their own short-forms as well and these change regularly.

That's why so many people like you are doing this by hand on a regular basis. Some of the consulting firms do list indexes to link various sources, not sure if you've explored that route?

As Shane and Marek pointed out this is a matching task more than a straight join. Many companies are struggling with this one. I'm in the middle of my work on this...

Jay

Comment: It's frustrating. I'm really surprised that they don't have codes assigned to them. The nomenclature is not at all standardized and even the asset classes don't match from one supplier to the next for the same year, let alone the same month. If you're working on this, I'd love an opportunity to discuss it in more detail: brandon AT bertelsen dot ca is me.

Comment: Definitely is, some have codes but they are indentifiers only in their own systems... I would like the oppurtunity to discuss and collaborate as well. I will pop you off an email shortly.

Comment: It seems I can only comment on my own answer....

so I concur with jmoy one should contruct an index (id) to use to join the different sources. The key is creating these indices ;) some of the standard stuff works some doesn't. It's a hard one. Are there any experianced data integrators out there who perhaps know something some of us may not?

Approximate matching and all surronding that are the most automated way I have found to begin to tackle problems like these.

Comment: Jay, I can't remember your email address - but I have a solution to this problem. We should connect again.