# R. Copying columns from one data.frame to another data.frame but the text for the values of the matching variable are different

Tags: r, merge, regression

I would like to copy multiple columns from one data.frame to another data.frame but the matching variable has different text for the same values in each data.frame.

Suppose I have two data.frames `df1` (contains 208 rows) and `df2` (contains 351 rows).

Portion  of `df1`

```
       Team   rank_A   fivey_rank_A
     Kansas        1              4
        UNC        5             12
    K-State       90             65
St. Bonnies       30             93
```

Portion of `df2`

```
           Team   rank_B   fivey_rank_B
 North Carolina        2              8
         Kansas        4            2.5
          Texas       30             21
        Florida       33             44
     Kansas St.       54             35
St. Bonaventure       84           80.5
```

I would like to copy `df2$rank_B` and `df2$fivey_rank_B` into `df1` but only for the matching rows (an inner join).

As you can see the problem is that the text for values in the matching variable `Team` are not always the same text; even though they represent the same value.

What I would like `df1` to look like after copying rows from `df2`

```
       Team   rank_A   fivey_rank_A   rank_B   fivey_rank_B
     Kansas        1              4        4            2.5
        UNC        5             12        2              8
    K-State       90             65       54             35
St. Bonnies       30             93       84           80.5
```

I am not sure how to do this in R, but I was thinking maybe I would use the letters in the teamnames and the values of rank_B, rank_A, fivey_rank_A, and fivey_rank_B to predict which rows in `df2` match with `df1`.

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: could you please post the command that you used for it.

Comment: Might be useful reading here : [merging-two-data-frames-using-fuzzy-approximate-string-matching-in-r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231993/merging-two-data-frames-using-fuzzy-approximate-string-matching-in-r) and in the subsequently linked q/a's.

Comment: @AlphaBetaGamma Correct. I am copying from a large data.frame to a small data.frame.