# how to match two column of one data frame with one column of other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two big data set

```
df1

full.name      first.name   age
bob marley     bob          10
jus bieber     jus          12 
xyz abcdef     xyz          14
abc qwerty     abc          15
hey hello      hey          10
jack ma        jack         12
zuke mark      mark         15

df2
name         age1
asd dfg      23
bob          10
jus bieber   12
xyz          23
abc qwerty   21
hey hello    10
jack         12
zuke mark    17  
bradd pit    50
```

and I want my answer like this

```
full.name      first.name   age     name       age1
bob marley     bob          10      bob          10
jus bieber     jus          12      jus bieber   12
xyz abcdef     xyz          14      xyz          23
abc qwerty     abc          15      abc qwerty   21
hey hello      hey          10      hey hello    10
jack ma        jack         12      jack         12
zuke mark      mark         15      zuke mark    17
```

I want to match full.name and first.name of df1 with name with df2 if

- full.name matched with name or
- first.name with name

and print value of age1 from whichever value of column of df1 matched with name(column) of df2

Comment: How about something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38246955/322912

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: not working plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be what you want although the `name` column is not in the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df3 <- df1 %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(type, name, -age, -rowid) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "name") %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  mutate(age1 = ifelse(is.na(age1), unique(age1[!is.na(age1)]), age1)) %>%
  spread(type, name) %>%
  ungroup()

df3
# # A tibble: 7 x 5
#   rowid   age  age1 first.name full.name 
#   <int> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>     
# 1     1    10    10 bob        bob marley
# 2     2    12    12 jus        jus bieber
# 3     3    14    23 xyz        xyz abcdef
# 4     4    15    21 abc        abc qwerty
# 5     5    10    10 hey        hey hello 
# 6     6    12    12 jack       jack ma   
# 7     7    15    17 mark       zuke mark
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "full.name      first.name   age
'bob marley'     bob          10
'jus bieber'     jus          12 
'xyz abcdef'     xyz          14
'abc qwerty'     abc          15
'hey hello'      hey          10
'jack ma'        jack         12
'zuke mark'      mark         15",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "name         age1
'asd dfg'      23
bob          10
'jus bieber'   12
xyz          23
'abc qwerty'   21
'hey hello'    10
jack         12
'zuke mark'    17  
'bradd pit'    50",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: i am getting error in rowid_to_column() data is missing

Comment: Did you load the `tidyverse` package?

Comment: Is the code working for the example data frames I provided?

Comment: actually i m having a different data set so i was working on that but data set is almost similar with the example

Comment: So my question is if the code works on the example data frames?

Comment: @xyz Glad to help. Please accept my post as the answer if it solves your question.

Comment: i want to ask you more question how can i print if there was  string in column age and age1

Comment: Not clear to me what do you want to ask. Please ask a new question and provide a reproducible example and clear description.