# Compare and join dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, duplicates

I have two dataframes that have mostly the same variables and I want to compare the cases of the two dataframes. I want to create a new dataframe with all the cases that are the same in df1 and df2.

Cases are assumed to be the same if all values of the variables that are **present in both dataframes** are the same. There is an exception for the variable "Age", where cases are assumed to be the same if the values have a difference of maximum 1 year and the variable "Time" where a difference of 1 hour is acceptable.

```
ID1 <- c(100, 101, 102, 103)
V1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 1)
V2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
Age <- c(25, 16, 74, 46)
Time <- c("9:30", "13:25", "17:20", "7:45")
X <- c (1, 3, 4, 1)

df1 <- data.frame(ID1, V1, V2, Age, Time, X)


ID2 <- c(250, 251, 252, 253)
V1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
V2 <- c(1, 2, 2, 4)
Age <- c(26, 55, 16, 80)
Time <- c("9:30", "12:00", "12:55", "18:00")
Y <- c (3, 2, 1, 1)

df2 <- data.frame(ID2, V1, V2, Age, Time, Y)
```

In this example ID1=100 and ID2=250 are the same and also ID1=101 and ID2=252.

I'd like to have a new dataframe-output
[like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s98Vt.jpg)

Note that it is not important if the values for "Age" and "Time" are taken from df1 or df2. The important Variables are X an Y.

I hope someone can help me out with this problem. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Kind regards
Philip

Comment: As an answer below suggests, base R does exact merges very well with `merge`. (There are also similar tidyverse functions.) But allowing inexact matching is more complicated. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231993/merging-two-data-frames-using-fuzzy-approximate-string-matching-in-r

Comment: Thank you Sasha for your message and the link. Unfortunately, I didn't find a proposed solution that is applicable to my problem here

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, subset(df2, select = -c(Age, Time)), by = c("V1", "V2"))
df3[,c("ID1", "ID2", "V1", "V2", "Age", "Time", "X", "Y")]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what you suggest is an exact merge. What I need to have is an exact merge for V1 and V2 but for "Age" a difference of 1 year should be allowed and for "Time" a difference of 1 hour.